# Using nth child to select items in odd number row

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a better or more efficient way of achieving this?

I’m basically wanting to select the first item in each row to remove its margin, marked in teal in my example. I’ve got it working with a bit of a hack but this content will be dynamic so it won’t really work long time.

I thought using nth child 7 would work but because of the odd number of items it doesn’t. Well I think thats why.

Take a look at my pen http://codepen.io/qwerty-design/pen/JGmYwo

Any tips most appreciated.

```
.brochure-download-thumbs li:nth-child(6n) {
  margin-right: 0;
  background: pink;
}

.brochure-download-thumbs li:first-child {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.brochure-download-thumbs li:nth-child(7), 
.brochure-download-thumbs  li:nth-child(13), 
.brochure-download-thumbs li:nth-child(19), 
.brochure-download-thumbs li:nth-child(25)  {
  margin-left: 0;
  background: teal;
}
```

The HTML is just a simple unordered list.

Comment: You have to post the code even when a pen exists because a pen doesn't keep track of history and so if you change your pen to verify the answers provided then your original question gets invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `6n+7` as the argument for the `:nth-child` instead of selecting the 7th, 13th, 19th, 25th elements individually.

```
.brochure-download-thumbs li:nth-child(6n+7)  {
  margin-left: 0;
  background: teal;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
.brochure-download-thumbs {
  width: 965px;
  background: #eee;
}
.brochure-download-thumbs li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 30px 10px;
}
.brochure-download-thumbs li img {
  border: 6px solid #1db4d3;
}
.brochure-download-thumbs li a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.brochure-download-thumbs li:nth-child(6n) {
  margin-right: 0;
  background: pink;
}
.brochure-download-thumbs li:first-child {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.brochure-download-thumbs li:nth-child(6n+7) {
  margin-left: 0;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sectionTitle">Mono Machines</h1>

<ul class="brochure-download-thumbs">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>

<h1 class="sectionTitle">Colour Machines</h1>

<ul class="brochure-download-thumbs">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://abs-ics.co.uk/assets/brochure-thumbs/mono/227.jpg" alt="ineo 227 Brochure" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Ineo 227</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

We could have used `6n+1` if you had wanted to select the 1st element also but since you only want elements from 7th onwards to be selected, `6n+7` is the option. It really depends the elements that you are trying to select. If the 1st element also needs the same setting as the 7th, 13th etc then it would be better to use `6n+1`.

Comment: In the example code it looks like he's applying the margin to the first element as well.

Comment: @Jivings: Yes, but the teal colored elements are only the ones from 7th. The question is a little unclear on that part and so I specified 6n+7 and mentioned about when 6n+1 can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
li:nth-child(6n+1)
```

That will always match the first item in each row of your example.

Comment: Your answer is also correct depending on what OP is actually looking for. Good that OP has both options available to them now :)