# How to select custom number of rows using CSS "nth-child" selector?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors, background-color

Basically I want to select custom rows and change their background-color, but I can't seem to find any information about that. I can do `odd`, `even` and some other formulas but can't do custom selection. I read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224572/using-nth-child-to-select-items-in-odd-number-row) and also [This W3Schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) but there doesn't seem to be an option for custom selection. All I can find are formulas and odd/even child selectors.

I have the following code in which I have selected `even` number of children **but** that is not what I want. I would like to *randomly* select rows and change their background-color. The table in the code below is the whole table and I don't need more rows/columns. Let's say I want to randomly select the following rows:

- the one having AAA
- the one having BBB
- the one having DDD

The only method of selection I know is `nth-child` selector but I can't seem to select the rows I mentioned above. How do I *only* select those rows?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                text-align: center;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 30%;
            }
            td, th {
                border: 1px solid grey;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: lightgrey;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Marks</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>AAA</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>BBB</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>CCC</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>DDD</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>EEE</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>FFF</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>GGG</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you mean custom selection and how does `td:nth-child(2)` not meet your expectations?

Comment: Are the rows you want to select random ? i mean you want to select 2nd, 3rd and 4th ? Will they always be 2nd, 3rd and 4th ?

Comment: If they don't fit a formula then selecting them **individually** either by class, ID or specific selector is your only option.

Comment: @MihaiT: Yes, I want to select random rows. No, not always 2nd, 3rd and 4th, *only* the ones that come first.

Comment: Then @Paulie_D is probably right. Adding a class to the rows that you want to select seems to be the best option.

Comment: Well what's the selection criteria then ?

Comment: @MihaiT: The result I wanted to achieve is exactly what José A. Zapata said in their answer. Yet it got a downvote.

Comment: because you miss clarity and details. if you do nto know exactly which rows you want to highlight at the start, `nth-child` selector is the wrong way to start with.

Comment: @tacoshy: Do you really not understand "I'd like to select custom rows and change their background-color. Say, **I want to change the background-color of AAA, BBB, DDD etc. How do I do that?**" Should I further clarify it?

Comment: I do... but is it always just AAA BBB and DDD? no if the criteria chanegs or you apply more then that or change, then as Pauli said, addidng a class in the HTML markup would be the correct way to go. stacking so many `nth-selectors` in this case is a very bad use for modern quality coding. thats why you have been asked by multiple person to exactly specify. And @Paulie_D definetly is one of the top `html`and `css` coders here.

Comment: Also SO is not for helpign an individual person with their requirements. Its for helping an entire community with `state of the art` coding. So "low-quality" coding or solutions should be down-voted in order to drop them down in the search list. As it would lead other beginners to copy "bad coding".

Comment: @tacoshy it should be clear now

Comment: José A. Zapata answer works if they are always 2nd, 3rd and 4th. You said they won't always be in that order. So that answer won't work. That's why i was asking about your selection criteria

Comment: @MihaiT I said that is the entire table and I don't have any more rows, so their answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: you said ": Yes, I want to select random rows. No, not always 2nd, 3rd and 4th, only the ones that come first. " . So not always 2nd,3rd,4th. How will nth-child(2) work if you don't want to select 2nd but for example the 5th element ? :) Next time please be more clear in your requirements.

Comment: @MihaiT I'll have to reread the comments and question :). Thanks for insightful comments :D

Comment: `I would like to randomly select rows and change their background-color. ` Randomly has nothing to do with your accepted solution. The solution you have accepted is very specific :) . Good luck. Happy coding

Comment: @MihaiT: Sometimes coding perplexes beginners :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you'd have to specify the elements manually, like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                text-align: center;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 30%;
            }
            td, th {
                border: 1px solid grey;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            tr:nth-child(2), 
            tr:nth-child(3), 
            tr:nth-child(5) {
                background-color: lightgrey;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Marks</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>AAA</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>BBB</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>CCC</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>DDD</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>EEE</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>FFF</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20-08-2021</td>
                <td>GGG</td>
                <td>000</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the cells containing AAA, BBB, DDD have a gray background now because in the CSS we specifically selected the second, third and fifth child.

Answer (score 0):

I know that some answers and suggestions have been given, but if you still want to solve this with CSS code then I would recommend you to take a look at a site to generate the `:nth-child` selectors. It's a quick and easy way to generate the selectors that you would like to have.

CSS nth-child generator:
https://nthchild.kawalekkodu.pl/en/

Alternative nth-child tester: https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

It helped me out many times. Might help others as well.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass in the index of the element you want to choose. Like "tr:nth-child(3)" will give you the element having index 3.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. This is not an issue of selecting every third element. I suggest you reread the question.

Comment: also a cruical typo: `tr.nth-child(3)` wont work as `nth-child()` is a pesudo-selector not a class. It must be `tr:nth-child(3)` does help though with individual selections

Comment: I understood the question. If you want to select custom elements, you'll need the specify the index of each of those elements. Like for selecting AAA, BBB, DDD you'll need to write 3 different `tr:nth-child()` for each index.

Comment: the OP never said which row he wants to select the row he wants to select may change all the time. thats why `nth-child` will not help if you dont know exactly which row to select before.

Answer (score -1):

u should select second child of tr and it will select AAA, BBB, CCC
reference: https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=01e519ca937a